# Second Div is not auto adjusting it's Height

Tags: html, css, angular

I have Two Divs which are one after another. when my above divs content increases the second div is not auto adjusting its height. i can't manually set height property in second div, as it's height is changing accordingly to first div.
here is how i tried to achieve it:
First Div CCSS:

```css
.amtx-message-handle {
  padding-top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: -1px;
  border: black;
  position: relative;
}
```

Secoond Div CSS:

```css
.expander-scroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 91vh;
  border-bottom: 17px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
```

I want second div to auto adjust it's height. so that scroll bar will be there till end of page.

HTMl Code:

```html
<div class="card msg-amtx amtx-message-handler">
</div>
<div class="expander-scroll">
  <div class="left-side-expanders">
    <ng-container #leftPannelContainer></ng-container>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side-expanders">
    <ng-container #rightPannelContainer></ng-container>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ng-container #deletedPannelContainer></ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: insert html pls

Comment: HTML is just plain simple. Two Different Divs That's it

Comment: @manishjoshi but there's something in divs, right? how can we help you if there's no code provided.

Comment: i think it is border-bottom problem of second div .insert html may be we can help you

Comment: @Huzee no border-bottom is not causing any problem. HTML is just plain simple guys, consists of two dovs with these class names that's i. Maybe you can suggest some way so that second div auto adjust its height when content in first div increases it's height.

Comment: Your Div are in the same div ? do you know what will be the height of the first div ? You can try to fix a max and min height to your second width. Without much html structure it is hard to answer...

Comment: no body would help you without watching  html

Comment: attached HTML Code

Comment: Thank you, So the first div as an auto height based on its content and the second has a minimum height or it can totaly disapear ?

Comment: yes first div has height based on content but i want second div such height so that scrollbar will there till end of page

Comment: Let me know if this is what you expect: https://codepen.io/Maxigui/pen/KKzVXYP

Comment: in the yellow bg div i also want scrolbar sothat i can see full view of div

Comment: Check again my link

Comment: if i am removing height from css, the scrollbar is not coming

Comment: The only height is on body and html. Which height do you remove ?

Comment: if i am removing height from expander-scroll then scrollbar is not coming